# how to disable future dates in material-ui datepicker in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

how to disable future dates in material-ui datepicker in reactjs?

I want to disable future dates that are after today's in material-ui in ReactJS. How can I disable future dates?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a property `maxDate` of `DatePicker`, that you can set to **today's date**, it will not allow to select the future dates.

```
maxDate = {new Date()}
```

Use it Like this:

```
<DatePicker
    onChange= {...}
    mode="landscape"
    value={...}
    floatingLabelText="Date"
    minDate={...}
    maxDate={new Date()}  //maxDate
/>
```

**Note**: You can specify the minimum date also, in `minDate`.

Check the [DOC](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker).

Comment: This still allows typing the future dates.

Answer (score 10):

With the current material-ui and if you are using **KeyboardDatePicker** then, the following will work

```js
import { KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';

<KeyboardDatePicker
  // other props
  disableFuture={true}
/>
```

Comment: This is the way to go now. It's enough to just write disableFuture, without ={true}.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<TextField>` component in material UI just give it a `type=date`.
If you want to use the min or max attribute you have to pass it through inputProps
`<TextField  type="date" inputProps={{ min: "2020-10-10" }} />`

Just make sure that the format corresponds to the type of the input.
`<input type="date" value="2017-06-01"> <input type="datetime-local" min="2018-06-07T00:00">`

Answer (score 2):

You can use disableFuture property with both **DatePicker** and **KeyboardDatePicker**

```
<DatePicker
    onChange= {...}
     value={...}
     minDate={...}
  disableFuture={true}
/>
```